# how to locally install C++ kernel for jupyter notebook on mac M1

Tags: installation, jupyter-notebook

I am considering installing c++ kernel for jupyter notebook on my mac.
So far, I have tried all commands mentioned from this page https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/xeus-cling in terminal and ends with,

```bash
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - xeus-cling

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/label/gcc7/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/label/gcc7/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I turned to the git page of `xeus-cling` and found an issue https://github.com/jupyter-xeus/xeus-cling/issues/474, so I stopped the idea of trying with `mamba`.

anyone has succeed in installing c++ kernel for jupyter notebook on your own M1?

I am using:
macOS 12.6.3, Apple Silicon M1;
python 3.8.1
conda 23.1.0

I am looking for a solution to intall c++ kernel for jupyter notebook locally.

Comment: I'm waiting for this also. See https://github.com/jupyter-xeus/xeus-cling/issues/411

Comment: In the meantime, I run my jupyter server in a docker container with various folders mounted inside. It's not great, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: **Update**: I worked out a way to run only the xeus-cling *kernel* in docker, and the server itself (and all other kernels) can run on my mac as usual. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77835361/2288986

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - xeus-cling

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35603637)